# Removing a live data Observer create inside a closure

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am having a problem removing live data observer created inside a closure.

The Observer is create like so:

```
recordingListener.startRecording() {ID ->
        this.ID = ID
        locationViewModel.getAllByID(ID).observe(this, android.arch.lifecycle.Observer {locations ->
            myViewService.showDataOnMap(locations!!)
        })
    }
```

I am trying to remove it like so:

```
locationViewModel.getAllByID(ID).removeObservers(this)
```

But it seems the observer is persisting even after removeObserver is called. My thought is that the issue is caused by the fact that the observer is created inside a closure, or else perhaps I am doing something else wrong.

Comment: Where exactly do you remove it and are you sure about what `this` actually refers to?

Comment: This refers to my MainActivity, my lifecycle owner. I figured out what I was doing wrong. After stopping and removing the observer I was accessing a newly created observer with the same ID again in another part of the class. I am using an extension of LiveData, Observe once method now in the subsequent ViewModels calls and it seems to have completely resolved the issue, and its now letting the old Observers rest peacefully 

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in subsequent calls to locationViewModel I was making more calls the same ID. This prevents the locationViewModel Observer from being removed.

To solve the problem, I am now using a LiveData extension ObserveOnce, in subsequent calls to locationViewModel. All it does is just makes managing calls to the ViewModel that only require a single response a bit easier.

I can't speak to whether it is the best practice or not, and its need probably stems from bad architecture in my app, but for this it works and works well so happy days, here is the Observe once code:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    observeForever(object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
            removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
locationViewModel.getAllByID(ID).observeOnce(this, Observer {locations ->

})
```